How to add time to date in PHP
I am trying to add the time to the date but I am having trouble with the correct code to do it.
$dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
$timeToAddToDate = 2:52; // This is from user input so it is not always 2:52 am o'clock, sometimes 21:30 o'clock depending on the user input;

I tried
$s = new DateTime($date_now);
$t = $s->modify('+{$timeToAddToDate} seconds');

$results = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$t); // this is not working`

echo $results;`

I am expecting the results to be "2024-07-28 2:52" or "{date today} {time input by user}".
I want the results then converted to timestamp and save it to the database column with a timestamp type.
So after the $results, I will convert it to strtotime($results) then insert it via sql query to the database.

Split the input and use mktime to directly create a timestamp…

I found mktime complicated, is there a simplier way? and how do I split that in mktime function

Why would you expect '+2:52 seconds' to work? 2:52 is not an amount of seconds. First convert the HH:MM format to minutes (e.g How to convert hh:mm:ss to minutes) and then add that as minutes

If you find mktime too complicated, another option would be strtotime, which "parse about any English textual datetime description".

For this you can use strtotime:
$dateToday = date("Y-m-d"); $resultTimestamp = strtotime($dateToday . " ". $timeToAddToDate); $resultDate = date("Y-m-d H:i", $resultTimestamp);

This is a way to go (you can compact the code, I probably overdetailed it.)
<?php

$currentDate = new DateTime();
$inputTime = '2:52'; // 2:52 without the quotes is syntax error

/*
Extract hours and minutes from the input string 
(you should also make sure you'll always receive your string with this format, never trust user input).
*/
$inputTime = explode(':', $inputTime);
$hours = $inputTime[0];
$minutes = $inputTime[1];

// Format response to string (or keep it as a DateTime object by removing the format method
$response = $currentDate->setTime($hours, $minutes)->format('Y-m-d H:i');

